# Ubuntu shell script: Get and echo time from ntp server without synchronization

Tags: datetime, ubuntu, server, ntp

Is there a way to get time using shell scripting from pool.ntp.org without update my machine?

ntpdate pool.ntp.org just updates my machine.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how strongly you insist on using ntp servers. Some of them still support daytime protocol and can be queried on port 13

```
nc time.nist.gov 13
```

But if you don't mind using http://www.timeapi.org/ then it's simple matter of using curl. For example to get current utc time you would use

```
curl http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
```

For more examples and capabilities, check link above.

Answer (score 1):

ntpdate has a "debug" option that does not update the time on your computer:

```
ntpdate -d -p 1 pool.ntp.org | grep "reference time"
```